# Image classification CNN model always predicts the same value

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, image-classification

I have a image dataset which have the following structure:

```
money_photo/
           100/
           50/
           10/
           1/
```

Each directory have inside 240 photos with the corresponding banknote value(100, 50, 10 and 1).

I'm splitting train and val datasets with **keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory** like in the following lines:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

Found 960 files belonging to 4 classes.
Using 768 files for training.

```
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

Found 960 files belonging to 4 classes.
Using 192 files for validation.

Every image is scalled to **180x180 pixels** and its normalised (0..255 pixel values have corresponding values between **0<=value<=1**)

Model is defined below:

```
num_classes = 4

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(num_classes),
  layers.Activation('softmax')
])
```

After training I have the follwing results:

Epoch 3/3
24/24 [==============================] - 10s 425ms/step - loss: 0.3214 - accuracy: 0.8866 - val_loss: 0.2449 - val_accuracy: 0.9115

The way that I'm using the model to predict:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from skimage import transform

def load(filename):
    np_image = Image.open(filename)
    np_image = np.array(np_image).astype('float32')/255
    np_image = transform.resize(np_image, (180, 180, 3))
    np_image = np.expand_dims(np_image, axis=0)
    return np_image

image = load('abd.jpg')
prediction = model.predict(image)

print(class_names[np.argmax(prediction)])
```

Why I'm getting always the same predicted value?

Answer (score 0):

Your model has a rescaling layer built into it so you should not rescale your input image. Just change

```
np_image = np.array(np_image).astype('float32')/255
```

to

```
np_image = np.array(np_image).astype('float32')
```